# Bless error when installing rEFInd

Tags: startup, efi, bless

I am trying to install rEFInd on my MacBook Pro 2018 laptop with the new T2 chip that adds extra boot security.

I have both used `APFS` and `MacOS Extended (Journaled)`. I have also disabled secure boot and csrutil.

When I install rEFInd using `sudo ./install.sh  --alldrivers  --ownhfs /dev/disk0s3` (where disk0s3 is my MacOS Extended (Journaled)), I then get an error when selecting the rEFInd disk in the `Startup Disk`, I end up getting an error saying that there was a bless error.

How would I install rEFInd on my MacBook Pro 2018 laptop?

**Edit**:

If it helps, I am on macOS High Sierra and will soon be updating to macOS Mojave in the next few weeks.

This is also the format of my disk:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         499.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTMGR                 307.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            199.5 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: As a kind of side question, I'm just curious to know what the reason behind wanting to use rEFInd is, versus just using the built-in Secure Boot manager

Comment: @JesseP. I want to triple boot with windows mac and Linux for my course.

Comment: Oh. I see. So, if it weren't for Linux being thrown in you'd just use Boot Camp, I assume.

Comment: @JesseP. Yep. Wish it was that simple!

Comment: Which Linux are you trying to install? Can you give the name of the ISO file? You can also install rEFInd to either a MS-DOS or a second EFI partition. Either of these should appear in the Startup Manager. I can not guarantee either will be selectable from the Startup Manger on your 2018 Mac. You would have to try  to find out. If you wish I could post instructions for the installation of rEFInd, but this would require for you to first post the output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Sure. No problem.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Also it will be Kali Linux I’ll be installing for my security course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to attempt to use rEFInd from a MS-DOS partition, then follow the instructions below. I have made the following assumptions.

- You will be reusing `disk0s3`.
- System Integrity Protection is enabled.
- You have booted to macOS. Do not boot to macOS Recovery.
- Secure Boot is is set to "No Security".

Below are the steps.

1. Enter the following command to change `disk0s3` to a FAT formatted partition.

   ```
   sudo diskutil eraseVolume MS-DOS BOOTMGR disk0s3
   ```

   You could also change the partition by using the Disk Utility application. Highlight the partition then select Erase. Use `BOOTMGR` for the name and `MS-DOS (FAT)` for the format.
2. I assume you have downloaded the current version of rEFInd (`refind-bin-0.11.3`) to your Downloads folder. Enter the following command to change to the root directory of the rEFInd download.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.11.3
   ```
3. Enter the following command to install rEFInd. I omitted `--alldrivers` since both macOS and Kali Linux do not needed any rEFInd supplied drivers to boot on a Mac. Also, adding `--alldrivers` caused rEFInd to hang on my 2011 iMac.

   ```
   sudo ./refind-install --root /volumes/BOOTMGR
   ```

   You should get the following alert followed by some additional error messages.

   ```
   **** ALERT: SIP ENABLED! ****
   ```

   You can ignore this alert. At the prompt shown below, enter `y`.

   ```
   Do you want to attempt installation (Y/N)?
   ```

   The follow error message was expected and can be ignored.

   ```
   Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc
   ```
4. Rename the `refind` folder to `BOOT` and the `refind_x64.efi` file to `bootx64.efi` so that the Startup Manager will include it as a startup option. This can be done with the Finder application or by entering the commands given below.

   ```
   cd /Volumes/BOOTMGR/EFI
   mv refind BOOT
   mv BOOT/refind_x64.efi BOOT/bootx64.efi
   ```
5. Add a label for this new startup option. Without a label the Startup Manager will show `EFI Boot` which may be confusing if you have other partitions with an `/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` file.

   ```
   cd /Volumes/BOOTMGR/EFI
   bless --folder BOOT --label rEFInd
   ```
6. (Optional) Goto my [Mac icons](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/) website and download the `mac-icons.dmg` file. Use the Finder application to mount this file. Enter the command given below to copy the rEFInd icon to `BOOTMGR` volume.

   ```
   cp /Volumes/mac-icns/OSX10.11.6/os_refind.icns /Volumes/BOOTMGR/.VolumeIcon.icns
   ```

   The icon shown below will now appear in the Startup Manager above the `rEFInd` label.

   [image]
7. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Next, select the icon labeled `rEFInd`. Finally, hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key and select the circular arrow below the `rEFInd` label. This effectively blesses rEFInd.

### Changing which drivers are used

The drivers used to access file systems by rEFInd are stored in the `/Volumes/BOOTMGR/EFI/BOOT/drivers_x64` folder. You can create a new folder named `drivers_x64_not_used` in the `/Volumes/BOOTMGR/EFI/BOOT` folder. You can then move any drivers you do not wish to be used by rEFInd from the `/Volumes/BOOTMGR/EFI/BOOT/drivers_x64` folder to the `/Volumes/BOOTMGR/EFI/BOOT/drivers_x64_not_used` folder.

If you are still getting a grey screen or a no entry sign, [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/70mtb2/refind_with_apfs/) shows that you will have to copy the apfs driver in order to boot. To do so, run the following command.

```
cp /usr/standalone/i386/apfs.efi /Volumes/BOOTMGR/EFI/BOOT/drivers_x64.
```

You may still have one boot option that shows the 'no entry' sign but the other option should now boot you into macOS instead of showing you a grey screen.

Comment: I was able to install it using your method however I have a few issues. When I boot to it, it shows two boot disks both named 'Macintosh HD'. When I boot to the first one, I just get a black screen with a white `no entry` sign. The second device, I am just greeted with a grey screen. How would I fix this?

Comment: Configuring rEFInd is an entirely different question from installing rEFInd. I do not use the `--alldrivers` option. [The rEFInd Boot Manager:
The Future of rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/todo.html) web page has a section titled *Known bugs that need squashing:*. The first item reports blanks screens on the newest Mac models. The posted solution refers to the removing of rEFInd's drivers. I could also post how to manual configure rEFInd to boot macOS, but I would need to know which macOS you have installed and the output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: Put the information in the edit of my original post.

Comment: Just found out that I was booting to a grey screen because rEFInd did not have the apfs.elf driver installed. I have edited your answer to explain how to do it.

Comment: @iProgram: Does this fix now allow you now boot to macOS from rEFInd?

Comment: Yep. I saw in the error that it could not read apfs. Looked it up on google and found that post. rEFInd now has the driver.

Comment: @iProgram: Is High Sierra encrypted on your Mac? I am trying to recreate your problem on a 2011 iMac.

Comment: It is not encrypted. I have created another post for this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338828/unable-to-boot-kali-linux-using-refind

Comment: @joevt: Since you added how to change the label to `rEFInd`, I decided to add how change the icon as well.

Comment: Thanks for these great instructions! I also tried using the `--ownhfs` method to install rEFInd on my 2019 MacBook Pro and found it didn't work at all. You've saved me a lot of time and headaches. The little optional step that gives the drive an icon was also a really nice touch. 